# GCM not working for release apk

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sony-xperia

Before any one marks this as a duplicate, I have been through every related documents and questions in Stack Overflow but I could not get my exact solution for my problem.

GCM for release apk works with other devices but does not work in Sony Xperia Z5 with Android version 7. Every other devices works fine.

I have tried with OnePlus 3 with Android version 7 and it works. The problem exists only with Sony Xperia Z5 (Nougat).

In my caseIi have checked all GCM key and tried with SHA1 fingerprint as recommended by few answers in Stack Overflow.

I have tried adding few lines in ProGaurd file as recommended in [GCM registration works for debug APK but not release APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132647/gcm-registration-works-for-debug-apk-but-not-release-apk).

But nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's device specific, maybe the app manager in your Sony Xperia blocks the notification of your app. There was no issue with GCM because as you've said, the problem exists only with Sony Xperia and works fine with other devices. Here's a [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z2/help/receiving-notifications-apps-t2925253) which might help. If `Setting > Personalization > Notification center` doesn't work, try to repair the firmware using [PCC](http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/xperia-companion/).

Comment: Thanks @abielita for the suggestion. I will have a look to your suggestions and come back to your answer. But there is no problem in the same device with debug apk. It only creates problem for release apk.